# Token error when sending Wechat message with Python

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, wechat

I have a Wechat subscribe page, and I set up in https://admin.wechat.com/ a token as well as the webhook URL of my server myserver.com/wechat/webhook

My server Python code authenticates Wechat server with signature check, nonce and timestamp and I'm able to receive messages from Wechat to my webhook.

But I can't send messages from my server to Wechat, I'm using the following code and the token set in the admin console as previously, and following the previous docs:
http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Customer_Service_Messages

```
# Parse the received WeChat message
message = xmltodict.parse(message)

content = message['xml']['Content']
fromUser = message['xml']['FromUserName']
toUser = message['xml']['ToUserName']
createdTime = message['xml']['CreateTime']

# reply to message
post_data = {
   "touser": fromUser,
   "msgtype": "text",
   "text":
   {
        "content": "Thanks for your message"
   }
}
api_url = 'https://api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/message/custom/send?access_token=' + token
response = requests.post(api_url, data=post_data)
content = response.content
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
{"errcode":40001,"errmsg":"invalid credential, access_token is invalid or not latest hint: [udQ9ka0880vr32!]"}
```

What token am I supposed to use? Or what could be the error? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be a permission problem... In my Wechat page admin console, it says I have Permission obtained for Auto-reply, but not for Service API.  Anyone can confirm this?

Indeed I tested successfully instantly replying to POST messages with an http response (Auto-reply or callback) http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Callback_Messages

And the Service API seems to not be working (which was the purpose of my question) http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Customer_Service_Messages